# How to backup my Ubuntu, so that i can clone the same setup to another PC?

Tags: 11.04, 11.10, boot, backup, clone

How can i make a boot-able CD of my existing Ubuntu including all the modifications i did?.

So, that i can use that CD to my another same new PC to start quickly all setup done.

**Follow up:**

```
$ sudo apt-cache search remastersys
$ sudo echo "deb http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/repository karmic/" > /etc/apt/sources.lits
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install remastersys
$ remastersys -h
Usage of remastersys 2.0.18-1 is as follows:

   sudo remastersys backup|clean|dist [cdfs|iso] [filename.iso]


Examples:

   sudo remastersys backup   (to make a livecd/dvd backup of your system)

   sudo remastersys backup custom.iso
                             (to make a livecd/dvd backup and call the iso custom.iso)

   sudo remastersys clean    (to clean up temporary files of remastersys)

   sudo remastersys dist     (to make a distributable livecd/dvd of your system)

   sudo remastersys dist cdfs
                             (to make a distributable livecd/dvd filesystem only)

   sudo remastersys dist iso custom.iso
                             (to make a distributable iso named custom.iso but only
                              if the cdfs is already present)

   cdfs and iso options should only be used if you wish to modify something on the
   cd before the iso is created.  An example of this would be to modify the isolinux
   portion of the livecd/dvd
```

Answer (score 3):

I have used [Remastersys](http://www.remastersys.klikit-linux.com) successfully to make mirror instalation DVD of ubuntu 10.04. I am not sure if it works on 11+ releases. I think it is worth checking it out. With a quick googling I found [this post](http://bikramkawan.com.np/how-to-install-remastersys-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/) but **I have not tested it**.

Comment: Did not worked. ls: cannot access /home/remastersys/remastersys//var/tmp/myubuntu.iso: No such file or directory

Comment: Sorry I am not able to try it now. I remember something about adding your user do the remastersys group or something like that. This could be the reason of the access problem you mentioned..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, your install is not going to fit on a CD. But a tarball of your home folder most likely will work unless you have saved things outside of ~/

There's also a new feature in Software Center to let you backup all of your installed packages online, then reload them from Software Center on another computer. Open up Software Center, press F10 and select Sync Between Computers and you can backup your configuration.

So here's what you might do:
1. Create an Ubuntu Installation CD (from an ISO)
2. Create a tarball of your home directory
3. Use Software Center, backup your configuration.
4. Install Ubuntu on your new computer.
5. Open Software Center and Choose Sync Between computers and sync the installed packages.
6. Extract the tarball to your home folder.

Sorry, I don't have a solution using a single CD.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I am writer for above post http://bikramkawan.com.np/how-to-install-remastersys-on-ubuntu-11-10-oneiric-ocelot/
. It works for me.I have successfully installed and back up my pc using remastersys.

Comment: Did not worked unable to create the file: ls: cannot access /home/remastersys/remastersys//var/tmp/myubuntu.iso: No such file or directory